# Give a big-$\mathcal{O}$ estimate for the number of times the algorithm needs to determine whether an integer is in one of the subsets.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity

Suppose we have n subsets $S_1, S_2, . . . , S_n$ of the set ${1, 2, \textit{...} , n}$. The a brute-force algorithm that determines whether there is a disjoint pair of these subsets is as follows below.

Based on my understanding, the algorithm starts by comparing set $S_1$ to all other sets $S_2, S_3, \textit{...}, S_n$. In the second round, it should compare $S_2$ with all other subsets $S_3, \textit{...}, S_n$, until we reach the last set and compare it with itself $S_n$.

**Question 1**: could you please tell me the rule of $a_i < a_j$ below in the algorithm?

**Question 2**: based on big-$\mathcal{O}$, the running time for comparisons is $2\times(n-1)\times (n-1)\times n$. However, I only see one comparison below in the algorithm not 2.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a mistake to me. The algorithm works (albeit inefficiently) without it. The inner loop can start with $disjoint:=true$

Comment: I don‘t quite understand what $a_i$ and $a_j$ are supposed to be. Should it be $i < j$? That wouldn’t make sense, since $j=i+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if $a_i \lt a_j$ line is a mistake.  $a_i,a_j$ are never defined and the algorithm does not need it.  The $i$ loop is executed $n-1$ times, the $j$ loop is executed an average of about $\frac n2$ times, and the $k$ loop is executed $n$ times, so the number of inclusion checks  is $2\cdot (n-1)\cdot \frac n2\cdot n$ with the $2$ coming from checking $S_i$ and $S_j$.  We don't care about multiplicative constants.  The algorithm is then $\mathcal O(n^3)$

Comment: I think the "2 comparisons" is one for each of $k \in S_i$ and $k \in S_j$. Not sure though.

Comment: @roundsquare:  that makes sense.  I have put that in.  Thanks

Comment: @RossMillikan. Thank you very much Ross. So for checking inclusion ($\in$) takes one comparison?

Comment: That is how I was taking it.  Depending on your computer, checking inclusion might take $n$, which would give another factor in the $\mathcal O$.  Comparison is a curious word to use for this.